# Rxjava event bus subscribing again on resume not working

Tags: rx-java, event-bus

I m new to RxJava and I m trying to use RxJava as an event bus. I m using RxJava example by Kaushik Gopal (https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/rxbus/RxBus.java).

Here is my RxBus code

```
public class RxBus {

 private static RxBus _instance;
 private final Subject<Object, Object> _bus;

 public static synchronized RxBus getInstance(){
    if(_instance == null){
        _instance = new RxBus();
    }
    return _instance;
 }

 private RxBus() {
    _bus = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());
 }

 public void send(Object o) {
    _bus.onNext(o);
 }

 public Observable<Object> toObserverable() {
    return _bus;
 }

 public boolean hasObservers() {
    return _bus.hasObservers();
 }
}
```

I m posting on a different thread but I m subscribing on a UI thread. Here is my subscribe code

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        protected CompositeSubscription _subscriptions;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            _subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            ....
            _subscriptions.add(RxBus.getInstance().toObserverable()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(final Object event) {
                            //Do something here
                        }
                    }));

            .....        
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {

            ......
            _subscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

When I first load the activity I do receive the events. But if I close and open the activity again (triggering onPause and onResume) I stop getting the events. Am I missing anything here ? Is this the right way to use RxJava for event bus ? Again I m posting on a different thread but I m subscribing on a UI thread. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Had to call _subscriptions.clear() instead of _subscriptions.unsubscribe();